# Could not resolve reference: JSON Pointer evaluation failed while evaluating token "components" against an unexpected Element

Tags: yaml, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using Swagger for the first time. The problem is with $ref when I want to set schema to make code cleaner. I am using YAML.

By the official documentation (The element of the document located in another folder – $ref: '../another-folder/document.json#/myElement' - [Swagger ref docs](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/)) this should work, but it does not.

[image]

I am getting this error:
[image]
And schema is not recognised at the bottom.

The folder structure:

```
--routes
|  L continentRoute.js
|
|-utils
  |-schemas
  |  L continentSchema.yaml
  |
  L swagger.js
```

continentRoute.js

```
...

// GET /api/v1/continents
/**
 * @openapi
 *  '/api/v1/continents':
 *  get:
 *      summary: Get all continents
 *      tags:
 *          - Continent
 *      description: Returns an array of continent data objects with id and name
 *      responses:
 *          '200':
 *              description: A JSON object with an array of continents.
 *              content:
 *                  application/json:
 *                      schema:
 *                          $ref: '../utils/schemas/continentSchema.yaml#/components/schemas/GetAllContinentsResponse'
 */
router.get("/", controller.getContinents);

...
```

continentSchema.yaml

```
components:
  schemas:
    GetAllContinentsResponse:
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          example: 1
        name:
          type: string
          example: Europe
```

What do I have to do different? The problem must be in path because when I put
continentSchema.yaml in same folder where is continentRoute.js it works and the schema is recognised at the bottom.

The folder structure when everything works (with  $ref: '#/components/schemas/GetAllContinentsResponse'):

```
--routes
|  L continentRoute.js
|  L continentSchema.yaml
|
|-utils
  |-schemas
  L swagger.js
```